# What’s best approach to load data source as teradata to destination as Postgres table using Nifi

Tags: postgresql, connection, teradata, apache-nifi

I am new to Nifi so could you help me to create a 
Nifi flow to copy the source teradata table to 
Target as Postgres table.

The intial process I started is copying the same 
Db as source and target (oracle).

ListDatbaseTables —> GenerateTableFetch
—> ExcuteSQL —> ConvertRecord —>
PutDatabaseRecord

How do I define the flow for teradata to Postgres 
When I am trying to pull the data from Postgres 
Getting error as “connection attempt failed 
Due to poolable connection factory”

Comment: Please provide the whole stacktrace of the error from nifi-app.log

Comment: probably `pull the data from Teradata` ? and about connection error - could you provide the detailed connection information and full error message from `nifi-app.log` file